# I learned basics of 3d modeling but not sculpting. What should be my next step?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

My main aim for learning blender was for rendering and then animation. I learned basics of 3d modeling but not sculpting. What should be my next step?

If I want to focus on learning rendering only, can you suggest any resources where a person has shared his rendering journey only? (material and shaders including)
OR
Anyone can guide me from here as how to move ahead on this journey or include me in their work or any other help will be really appreciated. Even if I am doing any mistake in my planning here then also do let me know. Thank you

Comment: Rendering is not something that can be done on its own. Rendering is the transforming of three dimensional data in a file to something you can see on screen. There is a minimalistic open GL rendering that occurs in real time so you can see what you’re working on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: Please take a minute to read the [tour] and the [help] section to learn how to make best use of this site. As stated [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. Start by asking concise questions that can be answered here, there are a number of talented users that can help you with specific problems. For discussions and opinions use a forum like https://blenderartists.org

Answer (score 1):

Well, I personally learned mostly from reading the manual, and got heavily bored in the modifier section, which of course turned out to be one of the most useful parts of blender ever to me. From where you are, I would learn about modifiers from the manual, and then get a hold on materials and textures. I was very confused about the difference between the two trying to figure it out by myself, but thankfully there’s a lot of good resources out there to look at.

Including the manual (I <3 manuals )